# Socket IO - NodeJS require external script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have a question regarding requiring scripts to the NodeJS / Socket.IO Server.
In PHP I can add the line `require('somefile.php');` 
Is there any option to include any JS files to the `NodeJS/Socket.IO` server? My server code currently has over 500 lines, I want to add a Require for each `Socket.On` to make it easier to read.

Is there a disadvantage?

Thanks,
David :))

Comment: Maybe this can help https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_modules.asp

Comment: If a module is not included with node then you have to install that package, once its installed you can then include it with a require statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can in this way,
Your `IO Connection` file,

```
var module1 = require('file1.js');
var module2 = require('file2.js');

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    module1(socket);
    module2(socket);
})
```

`file1.js`,

```
module.exports = function (socket) {
    socket.on('createroom', function (data) {
        console.log("create room");
    });
}
```

`file2.js`,

```
module.exports = function (socket) {
    socket.on('play', function (data) {
        console.log("play");
    });
}
```